# counting number of sacks kept in a stack in a criss cross manner using opencv or deep learning

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

We have two views for counting the number of sacks. The sacks are kept in a criss cross manner in order they dont fall down. So we need to first count the number of sacks from the front view and then the side view and then using a formulae we can count the total number of sacks.[image]

We will be calculating the number of sacks in criss cross alignment from the front view.[image]

Then we will be counting each block from the side view
[image]

Comment: OK, you told us what you will be doing, but what's your question?

Comment: and don't forget to show your own effort towards solving the problem, i.e. show us where you're stuck.

Comment: I want to know how to proceed, what libraries to use and how to acheive whats on paper